# How to load JavaScript file after launching Google Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, client-server

I have two questions:

1. I have a Google web app (created with google app script) in my G-Suite account. Permissions are set to Execute the app as: Me / Who has access to the app: Anyone

In addition to Code.gs the app has three files

1. "Form.html" (html interface)
2. "JSfile1.html" (Javascript routines)
3. "JSfile2.html" (Javascript routines)

The loading of the third file ("JSfile2.html") is optional depending upon the user (which is determined after the app is launched). Executing doGet(e){} I am loading the first two files and depending upon the user I would like to either load or skip "JSfile2.html". Is there a way to append
HTMLOutput after the app is launched. I am using the following code.

```
   function doGet(e) {  
   var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form');
   var js1 = include('JSfile1')
   HTMLOutput.append(js1);
   HTMLOutput.append(template.evaluate().getContent());
   return HTMLOutput
     .setTitle('BCAS, App')
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
   }

   function include(file) {
     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(file).getContent();
   };
```

2. Is there a way to retrieve information from users browser local storage before the web app is launched and make it available while executing doGet()

Answer (score 1):

No to both questions. The proper way to do this is by using [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). Call server functions from client side and adjust the DOM accordingly.

**Reference:**

[Client server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)